# Angular Output dinámicos ¿es posible?

Tags: angular, typescript

Tengo varios componentes padres y he creado un componente hijo común para todos que debe adaptase de forma dinámica y automática a cada caso, entre ellas varios botones que se van a generar con un foreach utilizando los datos que le mande el padre(nombre, clase CSS y nombre Output).

La pregunta es ¿Puedo crear Output de forma dinámica que apunten directamente a la función del padre correspondiente?

Una solución rápida que se me ocurre es utilizar solo un Output que mande un string o integer siempre a la misma función del padre y que este lo interprete y lo derive a la función correspondiente con un switch pero me parece una solución poco "elegante" y eficiente.

Por ahora lo que he intentado es hacer esto en el componente hijo pero el propio editor me da error:

componenteHijo.components.ts

```
@Input() misBotones: any[];
constructor() {
    this.misBotones.forEach(array => {
      @Output() array.nombreVariable: EventEmitter<number>;
    });
}
```

Por su puesto estoy enviando desde el padre un array con todos los datos necesarios:

componentePadre.components.html

```
<app-componente-hijo [misBotones]="botonesArray"></app-componente-hijo>
```

Comment: Puedes agregar la explicación de cómo ese hijo tiene varios padres?

Comment: Son simplemente diferentes componentes que utilizan este subcomponente o componente hijo para agregar uno o mas botones con diferentes usos dependiendo del caso. Enviándole para ello un simple array con los datos. Mas que un hijo con varios padres quizás seria mas correcto decir varios componentes que utilizar otro componente como un subcomponente.

Comment: Eso pensé. Con respecto al switch, has probado pasando al componente hijo las funciones que debe ejecutar en respuesta a los eventos? De forma que no sea necesario retornar un valor indicando qué función debe ejecutarse.

Comment: ¿Como? ¿Enviarle el nombre de la función del padre que debe ejecutar dentro del padre dentro de una variable? ¿Se puede hacer eso?

Comment: Sí, se puede. Agregué un ejemplo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El componente padre, dentro los datos que prepara para que el componente hijo los muestre, puede agregar una función que se ejecutará en respuesta a un evento sobre ese elemento que se va a crear.

En el ejemplo se crea un arreglo `data` que tiene objetos con dos propiedades: `eventHandler` y `text`.

El componente hijo recibe ese arreglo y crea una serie de botones y en respuesta al evento click, ejecuta la función contenida en `eventHandler`.

**Componente padre**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {

  data = [
    {
      eventHandler: () => {
        alert("boton 1");
      },
      text: "boton 1"
    },
    {
      eventHandler: () => {
        alert("boton 2");
      },
      text: "boton 2"
    }
  ];
  
}
```

**Componente hijo**

```
import { Component, Input } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "hello",
  template: `
    <div *ngFor="let d of data">
      <button (click)="d.eventHandler()">{{ d.text }}</button>
    </div>
  `,
  styles: [
    `
      h1 {
        font-family: Lato;
      }
    `
  ]
})
export class HelloComponent {
  @Input() data: any[];
}
```

[Demo en vivo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cb5qt1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)

Comment: Entiendo por tanto que si esos alert() fueran una función que esta dentro del componente padre ¿podrían acceder también? ¿O es necesario codificar la función dentro del deleventHandler? En cualquier caso esta muy bien.

Comment: Sí, claro. La función que se pasa en el `eventHandler` se ejecuta en el componente padre, por lo tanto puede acceder a todas las funciones que están en el padre.

Comment: Entonces en muchos casos esto puede substituir a los Output ¿No? Tan solo por curiosidad habrá que investigar sobre el rendimiento. Muy buen aporte.

Answer (score 1):

No puedes hacerlo por un sencillo motivo: las anotaciones/decoraciones `@Input` y `@Output` son usadas en tiempo de compilación, no de ejecución.

No existen en Javascript y se usan para añadir funcionalidad extra en tiempo de compilación, por lo que no puedes modificar dinámicamente el código en tiempo de ejecución.